# Delete all files with a certain extension using Android ADB

Tags: android, adb

How can I delete all files with a certain extension, for example .png using Android ADB?

Removing one file would be:

```
adb shell rm downloads/bg.png
```

But how can I delete all png images on the entire device?

Comment: On onrooted phones you don't have access to the "entire device", you only have access to the "sdcard" section. You can try `find /sdcard -iname "*.png"` to get a lost of png files you can access.

Comment: @Robert thanks for the clarification! How can I then delete all these .png files in the /sdcard?

Comment: `find` has an option to execute a command for each found file. Try `find /sdcard -iname "*.png" -exec rm {} \;` On Linux this should work never tried it on Android.

Comment: @Robert this sadly does not seem to work for me :/

Comment: please be precise: does the command not work (e.g. error shown) or does it not work the way you want?

Answer (score 1):

It's very close to what @Robert mentioned in the comments

```
$ find -L /sdcard -name "*.png" -exec rm {} \; 2>/dev/null
```

the only catch is that `/sdcard` is a symlink so you have to follow them (`-L`).